# IContextMenu::InvokeCommand, break away from job?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, jobs, createprocess

I have a child process in a job that has `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` specified.

When I invoke `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`, though, any processes that are started are automatically killed when my child process exits, because they are automatically included in a job.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found is to specify

```
JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK | JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SILENT_BREAKAWAY_OK
```

for the child process, to allow its children to automatically break away from the job.